# Xamarin Forms: Change language of standard controls

Tags: xamarin.forms, resx

I followed this guideline to make my app available in multiple languages: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/
I added a picker so the user can change his language whenever he wants but there is a small problem.
When the device language is English and the user swaps to French, my picker will stay in English as it is the system language (It says 'done' and 'cancel')
Is it possible to change that language to the language that my user selected?

Comment: At least for iOS you need to include the languages that you want to support in your info.plis file. Read my blog on this [here](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/localization-default-ios-controls/). But how to force refresh those at runtime is something I don't have any expierence with.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis They were already added in my info.plist. When i change the system language of my device, the language of my picker changes. So that's working fine. Unfortunately, it won't change when I change my language of my app.

Comment: You're specifically looking at iOS?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I've got this problem on iOS and Android (not developing for windows phone)

Comment: I don't think there is a lot of documentation specifically for Xamarin out there. You will have to work with the Android and iOS project directly, probably through the DependencyService. Also, you will have to do some translation from Objective-C/Swift and Java to C#. [Here](https://www.factorialcomplexity.com/blog/2015/01/28/how-to-change-localization-internally-in-your-ios-application.html) is a link to some iOS method and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52985/how-can-i-force-localization-culture-to-en-us-for-whole-applicaiton-in-xamarin) for (Xamarin) Android

Comment: Please do! I'm curious to see for myself now :)